# Unable to create session using SessionToken in okta POST /sessions API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, amazon-web-services, okta

I was able to get the sessionToken using username and password. But, after that I want to create the session using POST call as follows in AngularJS. The angular (entire web app) is hosted on AWS S3.

```
var session_data = { 'sessionToken' : My_session_Token}; 
$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'https://myorg.okta.com/api/v1/sessions',
       data: session_data,
       headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
       }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
       });
```

The error I am getting is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myorg.okta.com/api/v1/sessions. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have already added the CORS Allow origin header in Okta as well as S3 bucket.

When I try doing the following through terminal

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "sessionToken": "my_session_Token"
}' "https://myorg.okta.com/api/v1/sessions"
```

First time I get

```
{"errorCode":"E0000005","errorSummary":"Invalid session","errorLink":"E0000005","errorId":"oaefADOnPONTDidUZYyrVc5rQ","errorCauses":[]}MAC-S014568:~
```

second time, because of sessionToken is one time use only I get following error

```
{"errorCode":"E0000004","errorSummary":"Authentication failed","errorLink":"E0000004","errorId":"oaeI-KKSO-iRGSR1gmyUjBS8g","errorCauses":[]}MAC-S01
```

**I don't think the problem is because of the CORS header (Allow origin) as I have already added the origin.
Also, I cannot use SSWS {api_TOKEN} as my application is in angular and its risky to expose the api token. 
Any help will be highly appreciated**

Answer (score 2):

Okta doesn't support POSTing to /api/v1/sessions to set a cookie in the browser. For a simple use case, you can use the redirect flow:

```
window.location = 'https://myorg.okta.com/login/sessionCookieRedirect?token={sessionToken}&redirectUrl={redirectUrl}';
```

All the allowed methods of setting a cookie using a sessionToken are listed here: http://developer.okta.com/use_cases/authentication/session_cookie

Comment: actually I am not trying to set the cookie but to get the current user id and user roles, which I will get in the response of POST http https://myorg.okta.com/api/v1/sessions. Is there any other way to get user id and roles without exposing the SSWS API Token

Comment: After setting a cookie, you can get the current user id by making a GET request on myorg.okta.com/api/v1/users/me. However, you won't be able to call myorg.okta.com/users/me/roles, because it doesn't support CORS.

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/roles.html#list-roles-assigned-to-user doesn't have a CORS tag

Comment: Thanks Kevlened I also kept getting a CORS error when trying to post my sessionToken.... seems strange that we cannot do it on our own server's side.